# Automapper and nullable types

Tags: automapper

I need to convert date time values into UTC time zone. Some properties are declared with DateTime? (nullable).

How can I check for null and only if not null, then convert the date time?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to handle null, just a [type converter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html) for DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional mapping syntax as described in the link [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.0.0/Conditional-mapping.html)!

So in your case the baz property would be a `DateTime?`

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz.HasValue)));
});
```

Note that this will just cover working *if* the field should be mapped. If you need to do some additional work to get the mapping to work (e.g. mapping one name to another) that would be an additional mapping.